# Baking Image Textures in Blender yields black image for some parts

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I'm the same guy that posted the issue earlier with the sword that wouldn't bake correctly. The question was poorly phrased and would've required too much explanation so I've just gone and made a different weapon and isolated the problem. If you take a look at the screenshots you'll see that I used Image Textures to color parts of the "weapon", which is different from the image texture that I use to *bake* the weapon.

Problem is, it seems like any parts with this color image texture attached to it (not the baking image texture) turn out black after getting baked. Anyone know why this is, or what could cause it?

For reference, I'm using Cycles on diffuse bake with only color selected. I noticed in the output section below baking there is something that says Target: Image Textures, and it has a "clear image" button below it. Does that affect anything or do anything important?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I will be available all today to provide further clarification if needed[image]

[image]

[image]

I have actually just SOLVED this question myself by messing around. It appears that if youre using image textures, and decide not to use them, you need to *remove* them from the shader area instead of just disconnecting them. If you don't remove them before you bake then blender will take the existing bake and paste it over the image you used, thereby massively messing things up.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: If you have solved the question, post it as an answer yourself, rather than editing the answer into the question (don’t think “Reddit”). Other people may find this information helpful.